# Global Attractor Existence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

How do I know if a system of differential equations has a global attractor?

I am an undergraduate physics student. I am trying to understand what is the domain of applicability of [Convergent Cross Mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_cross_mapping). I tested it on nonlinear and linear systems of equations and gives counter-intuitive results. My hypothesis is that it applies only to dynamical systems of differential equations which have a global attractor. But I am new to this area. How do I know if system of diff eqs has a global attractor? Are there criteria for it? 
I understood the definition of the global attractor from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1164676/determine-which-sets-are-local-attractors-and-determine-global-attractors) and maybe [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2651765/global-attractor). But I am interested only to know if it has or not. Not what the global attractor is. 
Thanks in advance!

PS: I know this is a soft question and I am not sure if I posted it in the right place.

Comment: You might be interested in "Lyapunov stability theory", for a formal treatment the classic paper by Kalman and Bertram is one of the best: http://fluidsengineering.asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/article.aspx?articleid=1430520

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*There seem to be multiple definitions of global attractor, so I cover them separately.*

#### Case 1: Global attractors are attractors

Here, I assume that a *global attractor* is an attractor whose basin of attraction is the entire phase space. In particular, a system with a global attractor is never multistable.

I am not aware of any straightforward criteria that allow you determine the existence of global attractors and are applicable to a relevant number of cases.
For most complex dynamical systems the existence of attractors and their number is usually determined by simulations or thinking very hard™.

That being said, there are a few classes of systems which are known to have global attractors and, in certain cases it is easy to show that a system does not have global attractors.
Some examples:

- Linear differential-equation systems have a known solution, which has at most one attractor.
- Hamiltonian systems do not have attractors at all (only dissipative systems have).
- If your differential equation is $\dot{x} = f(x)$, a point $x$ is a stable fixed point (a certain type of attractor) if and only if $f(x)=0$ and the real parts of all eigenvalues $\nabla f(x)$ are negative. If you can find two such stable fixed points, your system does not have a global attractor. Mind that the inverse does not hold as not all attractors are stable fixed points.
- Ecological or metabolic systems are known to need a positive feedback loop to exhibit multistability.

#### Case 2: Global attractors contain all attractors

Here, I assume that a *global attractor* is a set whose basin of attraction is the entire phase space. Such a global attractor would be the union of all attractors. Most confusingly, such a global attractor would not need to be an attractor itself, since it is not minimal. Finally note that the union of all attractors of a system needs not be a global attractor.

In this case, all you need to show is that your dynamics is bounded, i.e., there are no trajectories going towards infinity.
Again there are some cases where it has been shown that such global attractors exist and in some cases it can be easy to show that the system has such a global attractor.
For example, if you know that your system’s dynamics is usually evolving around the origin, it may be easy to show that for points that have a certain distance to the origin, this distance is decreasing over time.

Comment: Take $\dot{x}=x(1-x^2)$ and $A=[-1,1]$. Then $A$ satisfies the continuous-time analogs of the definitions of global attractor given in the OP's references, but it contains two asymptotically stable equilibria, namely $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: @user539887: How is $A$ an attractor? It is not invariant under time-evolution. With the exception of $0$ all points in $A$ converge towards the stable equlibria ($-1$ and $1$) under time-evolution.

Comment: Yes, it is invariant.

Comment: @user539887: And how do you reconcile this with all points converging towards $-1$ and $1$? Just so we are on the same page, I consider a set $A$ invariant under time evolution if $ϕ(A,t) = A$ for all $t≥0$, where $ϕ$ is the time-evolution operator.

Comment: Take $x=0$ or $\pm1$. As they are equilibria, $\phi(x,t)=x$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Take $x\in(-1,0)$, Then we have $\phi(x,t)\in(-1,0)$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Take $x\in(0,1)$, Then we have $\phi(x,t)\in(0,1)$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, too. Consequently, $\phi(A,t)\subset A$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, from which it follows, by "algebraic" properties of the flow, that $\phi(A,t){\color{red}=}A$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, in particular for all $t\ge0$.

Comment: @user539887: Damn, I brainfarted there and missed that you entirely included one side of the basins of attraction of the fixed points in $A$. Anyway, to go one level higher, $A$ lacks other defining properties of attractors, such as being a minimal invariant set. The true attractors $\{-1\}$ and $\{1\}$ are also invariant sets and subsets of $A$. The definition from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2651765/65502) is lacking this condition for some reason.

Comment: The definition of **global attractor** in Katok and Hasselblatt's seems to be the analog of Hale's definition. Further, in Morse decompositions the invariant sets called attractors and (their dual) repellers should contain their own attractors and dual repellers, since otherwise the theory would trivialize.

Comment: Can we generalize your consideration of stable fixed points (in case 1)? If $x$ is a stable fixed point, then $\{x\}$ is attracting. So, two *different* stable fixed points yield two different attracting sets. If we've got two general different attracting sets, are we able to show that their basins of attraction are disjoint? If so, this should immediately yield that there cannot be a global attracting set in that case. I've asked for that there: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4063075/47771. Please take a look.