# Disjoint attractors have a disjoint basin of attraction

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, basins-of-attraction

Let $\Omega$ be a topological space and $\tau:\Omega\to\Omega$. $A\subseteq\Omega$ is called *stable* if for every neighborhood $V$ of $A$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $A$ with $$\tau^n(U)\subseteq V\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N_0\tag1.$$ $A$ is called *attractor* if $A$ is

1. *forward invariant*, i.e. $A=\tau(A)$;
2. stable; and
3. there is a neighborhood $U_0$ of $A$ with $U_0\subseteq E(A)$,

where $E(A)$ is the the basin of attraction for $A$, i.e. the set of all $x\in\Omega$ for which the orbit $$\operatorname{orb}x:\mathbb N_0\to\Omega\;,\;\;\;n\mapsto\tau^n(x)$$ is eventually in every neighborhood of $A$.

I've read that if $A_1,A_2\subseteq\Omega$ are different (maybe we need even to assume that they are disjoint) attractors, then $E(A_1)\cap E(A_2)=\emptyset$. **How can we show this?**

Moreover, I would like to conclude that in that case there cannot be a *global* attractor $G$, i.e. an attractor with $E(G)=\Omega$. This should immediately follow from the former result, if I'm not missing something.

If the topology on $\Omega$ is induced by a metric $d$, then $$E(A)\subseteq E_0(A):=\left\{x\in\Omega:d(\tau^n(x),A)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\right\}$$ for all $A\subseteq\Omega$ (and "$=$" if $A$ is compact).

So, in that case, the desired claim would clearly follow if even $E_0(A_1)\cap E_0(A_2)=\emptyset$. Now it clearly holds that if $x\in E_0(A_1)\cap E_0(A_2)$, then $$d(A_1,A_2)\le d(\tau^n(x),A_1)+d(\tau^n(x),A_2)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag1;$$ hence $d(A_1,A_2)=0$, but that doesn't yield a contradiction to $A_1\ne A_2$ (or $A_1\cap A_2=\emptyset$) in general ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of *attractor* lacks the following property that is usually attributed to attractors: An attractor has no true subset that is an attractor itself. One way to fix this is to require that $\mathop{\text{orb}} x$ in definition *basin of attraction* is not only eventually in every neighbourhood of $A$ but in every neighbourhood **of every point** of $A$.

Without that condition, you can have $A_1 \subset A_2$ (e.g., by $A_1$ containing one and $A_2$ containing both fixed points of a bistable system), in which case you certainly don’t have $E(A_1) \cap E(A_2) = \emptyset$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The concept of the "global attractor" is highly confusing for me. For example, in [this dissertation](https://math.uni-paderborn.de/fileadmin/mathematik/Lehrstuhl_fuer_Angewandte_Mathematik/People/Dissertation_Adrian_Ziessler.pdf#page=22) (Remark 2.1.1), it is remarked that "the global attractor contains every (forward) invariant set". While I don't see why this is true, it even confuses me more that it is subsequently stated that if the global attractor is compact, it also contains every compact invariant set.

Comment: Isn't that a triviality if the former claim is true? If the global attractor contains every invariant set, it clearly contains every compact invariant set (no matter whether the attractor itself is compact or not).

Comment: I cannot find a strict definition of *global attractor* in that work, but it seems to use a definition where the global attractor is not necessarily an attractor (by any common definition of *attractor*). I also share your confusion regarding the compactness.

Comment: I think the reasoning might be the following: If $Q\subseteq\Omega$, let $A_Q:=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N_0}\tau^n(Q)$. It's then trivial to see that if $B\subseteq Q$ is forward invariant (i.e. $B=\tau(B)$), then $B=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N_0}\tau^n(B)\subseteq\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N_0}\tau^n(Q)=A_Q$. So, every forward invariant subset of $Q$ is contained in $A_Q$. Now, if $A\subseteq\Omega$ is such that $\overline A$ is forward invariant and $U$ is a fundamental neighborhood of $A$ (in the sense specified in that work), then $\overline A=A_U$. From the former result, we can immediately conclude

Comment: that every forward invariant subset of $U$ is contained in $\overline A$. (In the work, $\tau$ is injective; hence forward invariance already implies "backward invariance"). Moreover, they assume that $A$ is closed; hence $\overline A=A$. So, everything is in accordance up to this point). **However**, they later specify that $A$ is "global" if $E(A)=\Omega$. Do you see why this allows us to conclude that every forward invariant subset of $\Omega=E(A)$ (so, not only the subsets of $U$) are contained in $\overline A$? It might be crucial to noe that $E(A)=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N_0}\tau^{-n}(U)$.

Comment: Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4065497/47771.